# Get specific part of URL and replace it

Tags: javascript, android, url

In need of help in getting a specific part of a URL and replacing it dynamically

for example:

https://m.facebook.com/logout.php?h=**BfcGpI0GW8PKKFtX**&t=1494184226&button_name=logout&button_location=settings.

For this example, i need to replace **BfcGpI0GW8PKKFtX** and load the URL before and after that point. Is there and way to do this? To be specific it would end up looking like this:

https://m.facebook.com/logout.php?h=**+replacemen+**&t=1494184226&button_name=logout&button_location=settings. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Will `BfcGpI0GW8PKKFtX` always be the value of h and is this within Java or Javascript, you've tagged both Android and Javascript?

Comment: Is u looking for android native or JavaScript change tag according to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a regular expression:

```js
var regex = /.+(\?h=|&h=)([^&]+).+/g;
var url = 'https://m.facebook.com/logout.php?h=BfcGpI0GW8PKKFtX&t=1494184226&button_name=logout&button_location=settings';

var m, newUrl;

while ((m = regex.exec(url)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      ++regex.lastIndex;
    }
    newUrl = url.replace(m[2], 'REPLACEMENT');
    // m[2] because the first match is the whole url and
    // the second one is "?h=" (or "&h=").
    // the third one (index 2) is the one you want to replace.
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = newUrl;
}
```

```html
<span id="output"></span>
```

<s>The only thing is, the "h" parameter needs to be the first one, after the "?".</s>
Edit: I adjusted the regex so that the "h" parameter can be anywhere in the url.

Answer (score 0):

If the part you want to replace is not always the same, and it is always the key **h** you can try:

```js
var str = "https://m.facebook.com/logout.php?h=BfcGpI0GW8PKKFtX&t=1494184226&button_name=logout&button_location=settings";

var result = str.replace(str.substring(str.indexOf("h=")+2, str.indexOf("&", str.indexOf("h=")+2)), "REPLACEMENT");

console.log(result);
```

Beware of any exceptions that might occur.